# A way to use Rails' form helpers without form_for or form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to iterate over my Rails model `FlsCenter` and perform some simple JavaScript when a particular ActiveRecord is selected.

How can I use something like `f.select` and achive this `<select>` tag generation without getting into any `form_for`. Must I use vanilla HTML?

I would like to write:

```
=f.select(:fls_center, FlsCenter.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, prompt: "Select a Program Center")
```

But outside of a `form_for` there is no relevant `f`. Similarly when I use `form_tag` and simple `=select` it does not achieve the desired results. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome - when creating a title to a question, don't preface it with something like "Rails:...". Instead, make the title a short summary of your question and, if you really think you need to add a tag, do so in the natural flow of the sentence. Stack Overflow's tags are used for searches, not the title of the question, so artificially stuffing tags at the start or end of the title only makes it awkward to read, which is counter to the needs of those looking for your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails' [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) in combination with [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) should do the trick:

```
select_tag('fls_center', options_from_collection_for_select(FlsCenter.all, 'name', 'id'), prompt: "Select a Program Center")
```

Comment: Note, for `options_from_collection_for_select` the 2nd argument in is the `value` and the 3rd is what's printed, so this configuration would create a list of `<option value="name">id</option>` https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Answer (score 2):

all the `*_tag` helpers are ones that are not bound by a form object, so you could use `select_tag` without a form

```
select_tag :fls_center, options_from_collection_for_select(FlsCenter.all, :id, :name), prompt: "Select a Program Center"
```