# How to submit 2 forms at once or combine two forms in one?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have a form that looks like this:

This is my attempt at combing two forms.

I have been told to just throw the create method from ChargesController into OrderController but the issue is that the Charges Form needs javascript as the token needs the "id="payment_form" to send the API .  So there needs to be a way to combine both forms by either just Ruby syntax, or possibly by Javascript.

Ideally I would like to it to work like this...

If Charges form submits successfully, then submit Orders Form.

```
 <form id="form-element" action="/charges" method="post" id="payment_form">


    <%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |form| %>


      <% if @order.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

      <script

        src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">

      </script>

        <div class="form-row">
          <label for="card-element">
            Credit or debit card
          </label>
          <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
            <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
          </div>

          <!-- Used to display form errors -->
          <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">

        <%= form.submit "asdf", class:"ripple-effect", id:"button-element" %>
      </div>

      <span class="token"></span>
      </form>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <script>

       ....
    </script>
```

Somehow i need to combine the top two lines together in one. all of my attempts have failed.

Any recommendations?

For any admins wondering why i'm tagging stripe and javascript - is because i'm thinking javascript may be a way to complete this and maybe people who have used stripe have had these same tasks.

JavaScript for ths Stripe elements Form:

```
  <script>





  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_25726263432532454320B8');

  // Create an instance of Elements
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      lineHeight: '24px',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission
  var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });

    });

    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
      var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
      var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
      form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

      //

      ["brand", "exp_month", "exp_year", "last4"].forEach(function(field) {
         addFieldToForm(form, token, field);

      //
    });

      // Submit the form
      form.submit();
    }



  </script>
```

Update:

Added these changes:

```
<%= form_for([@listing, @order], html: {id: "Orders"}) do |form| %>
```

Added this to the JavaScript:

```
    $('#Orders').on('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/charges",
          data: $('#payment_form').serialize()
      }).then(this.submit.bind(this));
  });
```

Comment: Solution may depend on which stripe flow you are using. Having 2 forms on same page that are related to each other seems strange to begin with. Only way to submit 2 is have at least the first one get submitted using ajax so current page stays active

Comment: I'm using stripe elements.  the reason i have 2 forms is because the one form will give directions to lets say, a seller, and the second form, the stripe elements form, will be the payment.. so there's no way i could combine the 2 with ruby alone? I would need ajax? I'll start doing research on it

Comment: I have also updated the post to includet eh javascript from the stripe elements form.  any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a rails expert but as @Charlietfl has pointed out, i think what you want is generating fields from `listing` and `order` objects WITHOUT using the `<form>` enclosing tags.

I used my `google-fu` and instead of using `form_for`[0](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) or `select_tag`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681076/a-way-to-use-rails-form-helpers-without-form-for-or-form-tag).

In this case, you will only have one form with Stripe's credit card Elements.

Comment: i've tried a few ways to combine the forms but haven't figurecd it out yet from ruby alone.  i do think hes right.  i need to use javascript to complete this and have the forms submit one after another on submit